# Are you late tonight? vs Will you be late tonight?

Tags: grammar

In the morning, my wife asked me " Will you be late tonight?".
So I answered, "I am going to be late tonight."

If she asked me " Are you late tonight?", is that question right ?

Either gramatically or semantically, does that question sound natural ?

Is there any of native speakers who can explain the difference between these two?

I'd really appreciate it if someone would do that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrase is:

> Will you be late tonight?

One is not "late" until a certain time has passed, so it is incorrect to ask if someone *is* late in the present tense when speaking about a later time (tonight).

You *could* ask:

> Are you *going to be late* tonight?

Using "to be" as an auxiliary verb allows for the different tense.